# Windows 7: Update gpedit device installation restriction

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, group-policy

I am experimenting with the Win7 feature of *Device Installation Restrictions* (like described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530324.aspx)): To test that, I uninstalled two USB sticks that have worked with that computer and enabled the following group policies:

- *Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings*
- *Allow installation of devices that match any of these device IDs* (with the Hardware ID of one of the sticks)
- *Display a custom message when installation is prevented by a policy setting*
- *Display a custom message title when device installation is prevented by a policy setting*

After a `gpupdate /force`, I tried to plug in the USB stick that I allowed to install: Windows makes the "new device!" sound and installs it. **Good**.

When I plugged in the other one, Windows brings up the error popup and installs nothing. **Good.**

When I plug it in again, Windows just makes the "device error" sound and brings up no popup. **Why?**

When I go and disable the *Prevent installation...* option or set it to *Not configured* and reboot / gpupdate, this doesn't change: **Windows seemingly has "cursed" the USB-Stick**.

Can anybody explain to me, why this happens and how I can change that (both the "cursing" and the not-appearance of the popup)?

Comment: ...and perhaps the reason for the downvote as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out in the meantime.

1. *You set up the restriction.*
2. *You plug in a new device.*
3. Windows recognizes that a device has been plugged in and that it does not "know" it. So it tries to install a driver and fails due to the restriction. When that happens, it shows a popup. The device gets added to the "known" devices, but in "error: driver not installed" state.
4. *You re-plug the device.*
5. Windows recognizes that a device has been plugged in and that it *does* know it. So it just tries to reactivate it and fails. Error sound. It does not try to search or install a driver as it previously failed doing so.

When you deactivate the restriction and re-plug the device, the behaviour is like in the last step: Windows does not try to install the driver, because it previously failed. **This is the "curse".**

To install the device nevertheless, you have to manually initiate the driver installation by choosing "Update driver..." in the device's details dialog of device manager. When the restriction is active, this fails, when it isn't, it succeeds.

Just as a side note: If you uninstall an already installed driver, it gets "unknown" again. So when you plug it in with the restriction active, you get the popup again. Once.